# pg connection bad when I try to heroku db migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to migrate my database to Heroku but every time I try it says this :

```
Running rake db:migrate on ? dka-site-list... up, run.4313 (Free)
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/pg-1.1.3/lib/pg.rb:56:in `initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/pg-1.1.3/lib/pg.rb:56:in `new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/pg-1.1.3/lib/pg.rb:56:in `connect'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:692:in `connect'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord- 5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:223:in `initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord- 5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:48:in `new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:48:in `postgresql_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:811:in `new_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:855:in`checkout_new_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:834:in`try_to_checkout_new_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:795:in`acquire_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:523:in`checkout'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:382:in`connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1010:in`retrieve_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:118:in `retrieve_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:90:in `connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:172:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:60:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:360:in `exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:369:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:444:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:10:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:121:in `with_friendly_errors'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `load'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I have looked at many different posts and can't find a solution that works for me. Any and all input is greatly appreciated. Here is a link to my github repository to look at all my files and code https://github.com/JDKrupski/dkasites2.

Comment: "I have looked at many different posts and can't find a solution that works for me"—have you read [the documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5#database)? Your database won't be on your local machine, but you can connect to it via `DATABASE_URL`.

Comment: You're running "heroku run rake db:migrate" but you're sure you've already created a db on heroku right?  Ideally you've already run "heroku run db:create" and if necessary pushed your local data to it via: "heroku pg:push name_of_local_db DATABASE_URL --app your_app_name